# WxPython, ListCtrl add rows to the top

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

I have a ListCtrl and i wish to add the new rows to the top of the list (prior rows to be pushed down)
can you help me on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The fun fact about the solution is, By mistake I had put `index = 0` and just observed that it updated  my list by putting rows on top. Even while appending a new row using `OnUpdatePList` function it appends in the top. Works pretty well for my application.

```
def OnUpdatePList(self, pobj):
    sr = self.index + 1,
    index = 0
    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, str(sr[0]))
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, unicode(pobj["title"]))
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, unicode(pobj["name"]))
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, unicode(pobj["date"]))
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 4, unicode(pobj["rdby"]))
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 5, unicode(pobj["dues"]))
    self.index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in method to accomplish this. You would have to save the data, clear the control and then insert the new row or rows followed by the original rows. Personally, I would switch to using the ObjectListView widget where you can use lists of objects. Then you could just insert an object into the list and reset the control.

Comment: I think you could be correct. But still I got this working just setting up `index = 0;`. I'll update it as answer.